# Dockerfile for PHP service

Tags: php, docker

I need to create a Dockerfile for my php service. I just tried many options found in web, and none work correctly. I have simple PHP project in /home/karol/docker-file/service/start.php. Really important for me. Thanks in advance.

Currently looking like this:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY  ./ /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /usr/src/service
CMD [ "php", "./requestdispatcher.php" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

```js
DockerFile

FROM php:5.6-cli
COPY  /home/karol/docker-file/service /usr/src/service
WORKDIR /usr/src/service
CMD [ "php", "./start.php" ]
```

**Build docker image**

docker build -t imagename .

**Run container**

docker run -it --rm --name conatainername imagename

When running as a service

```js
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY  /home/karol/docker-file/service /var/www/html/
```

**Build Image**

docker build -t imagename .

**Run Container**

docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name conatainername imagename

Comment: I think I will just die.... no such file or directory at COPY, when it is 100% correct.... and it is a web service which should be visible in f.ex. localhost:8080

Comment: okay i changed /home/karol/docker-file/service to ./service, and it works (sic!)... now I need a lil upgrade to show it at localhost

Comment: You need use apache then.. its listed on the reference page

Comment: seems to be working but when i type localhost:8080 this page isnt showing up, only "unable to connect".
I typed docker ps -a, and there is this container but exited some secs ago, shouldnt it running?

Comment: -p 8080:80 did you provide this at startup? Yes the cotainer seems to have crashed

Comment: start without the -d option, you should see the error

Comment: did you use the dockerfile i listed? i made a small mistake

Comment: Updated the Dockerfile, try now using the updated config

Comment: I have wrote my current Dockerfile in first post. I had to change address lines, because I dont know why full address shows there's no such file...

Comment: Shouldnt workdir be same as copy? Changed it... but still exits

Comment: I havent var/www/html/ directory. Looks like apache is missing (lol), I think i should in Dockerfile make sth to install it

Comment: Use the other dockerfile I suggested, `FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY  /home/karol/docker-file/service /var/www/html/`

Comment: Now its: FROM php:5.6-apache COPY  ./ /var/www/html/ File is in same directory as index.php. Is it ok? Now it's runing, but Unable to connect at localhost

Comment: Working, almost ;) when i run my php file, everything is blank (white page). This is a small MVC Framework, do I need anything else to work?